# How to mock AWS Lambda context when testing lambda handler in Go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I have an S3-triggered AWS Lambda written in Go.  I've been able to successfully test all of the ancillary code, however, I'm stuck trying to test the lambda handler.

Here's the signature of my handler:

```
func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, s3Event events.S3Event)
```

Here's the test code:

```
package main

import (
  "context"
  "encoding/json"
  "testing"

  "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
  "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestHandleRequest(t *testing.T) {
  // 1. read JSON from file
  inputJSON, err := readJSONFromFile("./testdata/s3-event.json")
  if err != nil {
    t.Errorf("could not open test file. details: %v", err)
  }

  // 2. de-serialize into Go object
  var inputEvent events.S3Event
  if err := json.Unmarshal(inputJSON, &inputEvent); err != nil {
    t.Errorf("could not unmarshal event. details: %v", err)
  }

  // 3. How can I mock the context.Context?

  assert.NoError(t, HandleRequest(context.Context, inputEvent))
}
```

I have no clue how I should mock the context.Context.  I couldn't find any examples online either.

Anyone know?  Does my code look idiomatic for testing an S3-triggered, Go Lambda?

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but, maybe take a look at [`lambdacontext.NewContext`](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambdacontext#NewContext) from the SDK. This way, you should be able to add the data, lambda would add, yourself. You can construct the parent context with [`context.Background()`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Background) and add a deadline/cancel it etc. using the other functions in the [`context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) package. I don't know, if AWS does any other magic with the context, thus this might not completely duplicate all functionally.

Comment: why is the `HandleRequest` having no `http.Request, http.ResponseWriter` pair? if it is a handler, how do you take care of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

‘context.Context’ is designed to be an immutable value (even though it is literally an interface). So I wouldn’t be concerned with mocking it.

There are two ways to create empty contexts (‘context.Background()’ and ‘context.TODO()’). I would start with those. If you want to set something on the context, check out documentation on the context package.

Comment: Yeah, I was beginning to come to the same conclusion that I shouldn't worry about mocking it.  Especially since I couldn't find any tests from Amazon which did.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Will `context.TODO` satisfy your needs?

https://golang.org/pkg/context/#TODO